# Implications of using an ampersand before a function name in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

Given the example:

```
inline string &GetLabel( ) {
        return m_Label;
};
```

Where m_Label is a private class member variable.

The way I think I understand it, this function will return a reference to the variable m_Label. What would be the implications of using this throughout my program and would it be a better to just return the value, instead of the reference? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It returns a reference to the private member.

There are many cases where this is desirable, but some care should be taken.

IMO it's generally not a good idea to return a copy of an internal object that is not an integral type, for overall performance reasons. Yes I know, premature optimization is not good, but this is not really optimization, it's just a good performance practice that allows the caller to determine the performance implications; if it wants a copy, it can just not declare the variable that it's assigning it to as a reference.

There are 2 general rules of thumb I use here:

1) If you don't want the caller to be able to modify the private object directly, declare the return value as a const reference:

```
inline const string& GetLabel() const{ return m_Label; }
```

2) A caller should never store the reference returned from a class method, it should only be used locally where the parent object is guaranteed to be in scope.

If for some reason you need callers to be able to store a reference to your internal objects, use smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 14):

The ampersand isn't before the function name so much as it's after the return type. it returns a reference to a `string`.

The implication of this is that a caller of this function could modify the value of `m_label` through the reference. On the other hand, it avoids copying the string. You might want the reference and the function to be `const`, like so:

```
inline const string& GetLabel() const
{
    return m_Label;
}
```

Best of both worlds. You avoid the copy, but callers can't change your object.

Comment: Indeed, you probably want _both_ the const and non-const versions.

Comment: @ildjam That is only partly true. Usually you will only want to provide the const version, unless you have a reason to want to allow callers to modify the object directly. If you do provide the non-const version, then you should also provide the const version, so that you can still get read-only access where you have a const reference to the parent object.

Comment: @Gerald : Sorry, I should clarify -- what I meant was, if you want the non-const version that returns a reference, then you almost certainly want a const version as well.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a reference means that the calling code can modify the value of your member variable after you return. That's very dangerous, unless you intended for that to happen.

Better is a `const` reference, or return by value (without the `&`).

Answer (score 2):

One implication is that if the enclosing object is destructed, the reference becomes invalid:

```
Object* o = new Object;
string& label = o->GetLabel();
delete o;
// label becomes a dangling reference here.
```

Another implication is that a caller may modify the string. You can remedy that by returning a const reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're are correct. It's a reference to the string member.

The implication will be that if a caller were to assign a value or otherwise modify the returned string that they would also be modifying the member variable. If this is not the intent you may want to return a copy by value to avoid breaking encapsulation.