# Output in c++ and why?

Tags: c++, output, pass-by-reference

code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int &fun()
{
    int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

output wil be 10 , tell me how and when int x = 10 is changed to static int x = 10 output will be 30 .Explain both of the cases .

Comment: This is phrased almost like an interview question (and if it is, IMO it's not a very good one).

Comment: I would say a homework question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610350/implications-of-using-an-ampersand-before-a-function-name-in-c

Comment: Why not determine the output by executing the code?

Comment: *output will be 10* Not really.

Comment: @tc: Correct. Output could be: it overwrites your stack and reformats your hard disk. Not a good interview/homework question, unless it's a trick question.

Comment: @david.pfx i would say it is a reasonable beginner question. Just not something you should post on SO.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior. You are returning a reference to a local variable whose lifetime has ended at the end of the function.

It's quite amusing what g++ does with this code:

At [`-O0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c016bd55544eff5), it prints `10`.

At [`-O1`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f3ecbe1c9c22eaf), it prints `30`.

At [`-O2`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/844c6543d2e11232) and [`-O3`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07a9d3e52e8c43b), it prints `0`.

If you declare `x` as `static`, then it has static storage duration, which means that its lifetime doesn't end when the function returns, which means that it is legal to return a reference to it. All calls to `foo` will return a reference to the same `int`.