# What means &-symbol before getter?

Tags: c++

What means '&' before getter?

```
const std::string &getName() const {
        return Name;
}
```

getter was generated by CLion ide

Comment: It means it returns a reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implications of using an ampersand before a function name in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610350/implications-of-using-an-ampersand-before-a-function-name-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the return value's data type.

Rearranging whitespace,

```
const std::string&
getName()
const
{...}
```

This is a function named `getName` which takes no parameters, doesn't modify object members, and which returns a value of type `const std::string&`.  This data type can be read as "reference to a const string".