# In C++ what is the difference between *function(arguments..) and function(arguments)

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I see functions of the type:

```
data_type *function_name(arguments...)
```

and:

```
data_type function_name(arguments...)
```

I'm trying to learn when which one should be used. Why is this done in the example below? (This is from a textbook for a course.) When should I write functions like these?

```
struct Tower
{
    string name;
    Tower *link;
};

Tower *createTower(string name, Tower *link);
```

Further can someone clarify this?

```
Tower* createTower(string name, Tower *link)
{
    Tower* tp = new Tower;
    tp->name = name;
    tp->link = link;
    return tp;
}

Tower* createBeconsOfGondor(){
    Tower *tp = createTower("Rohan", NULL); // Points to nothing
    tp = createTower("Halifiren", tp); // Still returns pointer?
}
```

In the second line of the createBeconsOfGondor() function, how is the return of that function still a pointer?

Comment: The * applies to the thing which comes before it (Tower), not the name of the function. This function returns a *pointer to* a Tower. (Just as the second member of `struct Tower` is a *pointer to* a Tower.)

Comment: One returns a pointer and the other does not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8610350/10077

Comment: Follow up question added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Tower *createTower(string name, Tower *link);` returns a pointer to a `Tower` object. The asterisk before the function name is just specifying that the return type is a pointer.

You can also write the function definition this way which is equivalent but (in my opinion) more clear:

```
Tower* createTower(string name, Tower* link);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it more clear. I now understand that whenever I want to return a pointer to a struct, this makes sense. Also, is this a function pointer?

Comment: A function pointer points to the memory address of an actual function, rather than some data type like an `int` or `struct`. For example, you could define `Tower* (*func_ptr) (string, Tower*)`. Then `func_ptr` can be set to the address of any function that takes a `string` and `Tower*` as arguments, and returns a `Tower*`. So you can set `func_ptr = &createTower` Then you can call `func_ptr(name, link)` and the same code as `createTower` will be executed. You can use function pointers to swap out function code as needed based on changing conditions.

Comment: Edited question, extended to ask a follow up question.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the function returns a pointer, rather than an object.

For example

```
Tower createTower(string name, Tower *link);
```

returns a Tower object while

```
Tower *createTower(string name, Tower *link);
```

returns a pointer to a tower object.

Answer (score 0):

> which one should be used.

Note that the first form:

```
Tower  createTower(...);
```

might be used as assignment (thus extending the instance's life), as in

```
...
Tower T1 = createTower(...);  
...
```

or, you might use as an anonymous temporary

```
 std::cout << createTower(...) << ...
```

---

If Tower is BIG, you might have motivation to keep the expensive instance around for more than just the print duration ... so maybe use the former and do

```
std::cout << T1 << ...
```

Else, if you are worried about stack space, and not so worried about remembering to not-leak-memory, then you have motivation to dynamically allocate the instance in the heap (this also supports a long-life-span)

```
 Tower* T1 = createTower(...);  // BIG tower in heap

 std::cout << *T1 << ....

 // .... and some time later, you should remember to 

 delete T1;
```

Others would recommend you use a smart pointer (and learn to use scope) to control when the delete should occur.

---

Summary:

stack vs heap vs size of instance

life span using scope controls

Comment: Thanks, this does make it clear. Is there a good reference on smart pointers I can refer? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

Tower *createTower(string name, Tower *link);
THIS IS USED WHEN YOU ARE RETURNING A TOWER(MEANS A STRUCTURE) IN YOUR FUNCTION NAMED createTower(THIS IS A FUNCTION POINTER WHICH WILL RETURN A STRUCTURE)

Comment: From what I'm learning, this would not be a function pointer. The function pointer equivalent should be -
`Tower* (*createTower)(string name, Tower *link)`
Correct me if I'm wrong